# android imageview wrap_content

Tags: android, imageview, width, fill-parent

Hello everyone and thanks for your help.

I have a project in Android Studio.

I am using an ImageView inside vertical LinearLayout.

Here are my parameters;

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/myimg"
/>
```

You can see my image down below (red block) and imageview borders (blue line) 
there is no problem with width, it is %100 of my layout, but I want my image to fit the area while keeping the aspect ratio. as you can see in image there are white spaces, the ImageView height is bigger than my image, how can I fit image in ImageView?

I want this because I want that image to fit the width even the phone is portrait or landscape.

[image]

Comment: Instead of android:src, Use android:background and then check.It may get the required effect as you need.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the solution
`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: you saved me bruh

Answer (score 0):

The size of the `imageview` is correct.You have to scale your images accordingly.`ImageView` has property of scaling.Try this `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and let me know.

Comment: when i use "fitXY", my image's aspect ratio is changing and my image looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

your code is write but i don't know about parent layout and you image background is white & red part is middle in this background.

Here is code with parent layout relative

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/red"
     />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For `ImageView`, `android:scaleType="fitXY"` will loss the aspectration. Its better to use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and set the background for the `imageView transparent`.

If you dont want to keep aspectration, then `setbackground()` or `fitxy` will do your requirement

Answer (score 0):

In imageview, there is a option of center crop -

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

What it will do is that it will crop the image from center. The output will be like -

[image: resized]